# codeigniter template, how to add a sidebar

Tags: git, codeigniter, download, github, project

I have download a simple template system and put it to my codeigniter project, but I want to show something in my sidebar, and maybe on my footer.

Can you guys tell me how or fork my project on github and edit my file(s) so I can see what to do.  :)

[Here is my project on github.](https://github.com/SimonJ/Hip-hop-project)
https://github.com/SimonJ/Hip-hop-project

Comment: you're asking us to write *something* for you? be more specific.

Comment: i want to know how to add a sidebar function, så i can echo it out like this <?= $sidebar ?>, and then load my data from the controller to the $sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with your CI template library, however I can recommend either of the following as having the flexibility you require:

http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/index.html
[http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-template/](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-template)

Comment: i have try http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/start.html but i cold not find out how to include it and set it up, do you think you can do it via github so i can see what you do and learn a little :)?

Comment: @Sjmon the user guide for this library is really easy to follow http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

Comment: i just cant see how i add a view in my controller to the template lib

Comment: do you know how to add a view in my controller to the template ?

Comment: @Sjmon - the documentation as linked to above really is all you need to get started, and answers all your questions.